# javascript create an iframe with strict doctype

Tags: javascript, iframe, doctype

I'm building a widget that can be embedded in other sites. The widget is an iframe that is created using `document.write()` however I don't know how to apply the iframe doctype using javascript.

Here is my code:

```
document.write("<iframe scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\">");
document.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\"   \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">");
document.write("<html>");
document.write("<head></head><body></body>");
document.write("</html>");
document.write("</iframe>");
document.write("</div>");
```

The iframe is created but I the doctype is not applied.
is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid this is not really working. All elements between `iframe` tags are in the original page, and are shown, if the browser doesn't support iframes. What you get with this code is only an iframe with `src="about:blank"`. Please check this: [MDN: `<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe).

Comment: @Teemu oh.. I see.. but the question still remains. I created an inframe with javascript and I can add elements to iframe using javascript. is there a way to add doctype?

Comment: If you mean, that you really "document.write()" some elements between body tags in your code, and they also can be seen in the `iframe`, this question would be beyond my knowledge : ).

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1169519) might also be interesting reading...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to write into the `iframe`, you'll first need to create it, attach it to the document, and then reach inside of it to get a handle on its `contentDocument`.

Here is some sample code:

```
// create the iframe and attach it to the document
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

// find the iframe's document and write some content
var idocument = iframe.contentDocument;
idocument.open();
idocument.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
idocument.write("<html>");
idocument.write("<head></head>");
idocument.write("<body>this is the iframe</body>");
idocument.write("</html>");
idocument.close();

// now have a look at your creation in the console
console.log(idocument);
```

See it working in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XuXtp/15/).

Answer (score 2):

You could also use an HTML5 `srcdoc` attribute to specify your iframe's content.

```
document.getElementById('myFrame').srcdoc = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC....";
```

You'll have to check if `srcdoc` is supported by your browser.